# Parametrizing a Cylinder using Cylindrical Coordinates?

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, parametric, parametrization, cylindrical-coordinates

Let $W$ be a cylinder (the curved 2-dimensional surface only—not the top, bottom or solid inside) defined by $x^2 + y^2 = 16$, with $0 ≤ z ≤ 9.$ Parametrize $W$ using cylindrical coordinates.

Would this just be:

$$x=rcost(\theta),y=rsin(\theta), z=z. 0 \leq \theta \le 2\pi, 0 \leq r \le 4 $$

I don't get the "(the curved 2-dimensional surface only—not the top, bottom or solid inside)" part of the question. Is z just equal to z, since the cylinder's height depends on z? Is my parametrization correct?

Comment: Since you only want the surface of the cylinder, $r$ should just be equal to $4$. Anything smaller than $4$ parametrises the inside of the cylinder instead of its surface. Otherwise, you're good.

Comment: roll up a sheet of paper and tape the two opposite edges together; that's  "(the curved 2-dimensional surface only—not the top, bottom or solid inside)"

Answer (score 2):

Since you want only the surface of the cylinder with height from $0$ to $9$ on the $z$ axis, the parametric equation is:
$$
\begin{cases}
x=4\cos \theta\\
y=4\sin \theta\\
z=t
\end{cases}
$$ 
with $0  ≤\theta < 2\pi$ and $0 ≤ t≤ 9$

Comment: How would we parametrize this if we did include the entire boundary: sides, top, and bottom?